# How does SS, and other network programs, look up a port name from a port number?

Tags: centos, networking

SS, netstat, and tcpdump, to name a few programs, will all convert a port number to a name when recognized.  So a connection on port 22 will instead be shown as 'ssh', as an example.

I'm wondering how this mapping is done?  I assume that the programs aren't each hardcoding a list of mappings?  Is there a central program or service responsible for helping networks map port number to name?

Related question, when I run SS on the same version of linux (6.9, so a bit old) I'm getting different behaviors.  On the VM I was testing on the command 'ss -a' lists a program on port 11001; On a bare metal machine with the same OS & command the port is instead listed as metasys.  It's easy enough to fix my script to get around the problem, but I'm curious why one serve recognizes port 11001 and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically with the `getservbyport()` API which is an interface to the *Name Service* framework.

It's the same family of functions that resolve IP addresses to host names, user names to user ids and so on.

`getservbyport()` will typically look at `/etc/nsswitch.conf` (which lists which database to use for each of the category), for the entry for `services`.

If the entry for `services` shows `files`, then the `/etc/services` file as a flat text file will be used, like `/etc/passwd` would be used if `files` was mentioned for `passwd` (the user database).

You can have other forms of databases. On GNU systems, if there's a *`xyz`* database listed, it would be queried using a `libnss_xyz.so` shared library loaded on demand.

Other than `files`, common ones are `db`, `nis`, `nisplus`, `ldap`...

On simple deployments, it's usually only `files`, so `/etc/services`.